# Estimated data and server data does not match Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing

I'm developing a chat app and I'm using Parse for backend.
I have a Discussion table to save Discussion between 2 user.

```
@interface Discussion : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, retain) PFUser * customer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PFUser * creator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Quote * quote;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastMessageTime;
@property long messageCount;

@end
```

I have a Message table to save message.

```
@interface Message : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, retain) PFUser * sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Discussion * discussion;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * content;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PFFile * image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PFFile * imageThumb;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PFFile * video;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PFFile * videoThumb;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PFGeoPoint * location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PFFile * sound;

@end
```

When user chatting, I use cloud code to update lastMessageTime and messageCount.
I want to show a list of people with small label that shows messageCount, and I have a NSTimer to call it automatically each 3.0 seconds.

[image: messagePage]

But when I get new Dicussion, its estimatedData and serverData do not matchs.

[image]

I have no idea about this. Please give me your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem when working on Android Parse SDK.

I think you have edited `messageCount` on both server side via Cloud Code script and client side via Object-C.

To fix it, you must edit only on client side or server side and sync to another side.

Thanks.